# Prevent Sheetjs / xlsx npm from modifying date while reading from excel sheet

Tags: sheetjs

I have been using XLSX npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)  to read excel and csv.
I had been having problem with configuring date related params.
I initially had code like:

```
 const wb = XLSX.readFile(strFilePath, {
                    type: 'file', 
                    cellDates: true, dateNF: 'mm/dd/yyyy'            
 });
                
             
                const json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]], {
                    defval: "",
                    raw: false,
                    forceQuotes: true,
                    blankrows: true,
                });
```

With this above code, if a date like '12/$8/2022' is entered, it got formatted as '12/08/2022' which was unexpected.

So i changed readFile to:

```
const wb = XLSX.readFile(strFilePath, {
                        type: 'file', 
                        raw:true            
     });
```

With this, when i try to read 9/9/2022, it is read as 9/9/22.

What need to be added to read date as is from excel/csv without formatting?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add any format here.

```
const wb = XLSX.readFile(strFilePath, {
                            type: 'file', 
                            raw:true            
         });
```

No problem at what format date in your excel.Just read the excel file. If the date format ISO, You may use momentjs

Like this `moment(head_val.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")`